# Efficient way to detect "rank of corner" in flattened multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, optimization

This is a small piece of very frequently-called code, and part of a convolution algorithm I am trying to optimise (technically it's my first-pass optimisation, and I have already improved speed by a factor of 2, but now I am stuck):

```
inline int corner_rank( int max_ranks, int *shape, int pos ) {
  int i;
  int corners = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i < max_ranks; i++ ) {
    if ( pos % shape[i] ) break;
    pos /= shape[i];
    corners++;
  }
  return corners;
}
```

The code is being used to calculate a property of a position `pos` within an N-dimensional array (that has been flattened to pointer, plus arithmetic). `max_ranks` is the dimensionality, and `shape` is the array of sizes in each dimension.

An example 3-dimensional array might have `max_ranks = 3`, and `shape = { 3, 4, 5 }`. The schematic layout of the first few elements might look like this:

```
 0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
 [0,0,0] [1,0,0] [2,0,0] [0,1,0] [1,1,0] [2,1,0] [0,2,0] [1,2,0] [2,2,0]

 Returned by function:
 3       0       0       1       0       0       1       0       0
```

Where the first row 0..8 shows the index offset given by `pos`, and the numbers below give the multi-dimensional indices. Edit: Below that I have put the value returned by the function (the value of 2 is returned at positions 12, 24 and 36).

The function is effectively returning the number of "leading" zeros in the multi-dimensional index, and is designed as it is to avoid needing to make a full conversion to array indices on every increment.

Is there anything I can do with this function to make it inherently faster? Is there a clever way of avoiding `%`, or another way to calculate the "corner rank" - apologies by the way if it has a more formal name that I do not know . . .

Comment: After asking, I have figured that I can memoise this function for the inner loop, and get another performance boost from that, but it is still getting called for every position in an array (e.g. every colour channel value in an image), so I am still interested in answers. The impact of memoising also backed up my analysis that this is a costly function.

Comment: You can also use `div_t x = div(pos, shape[i]); if (x.rem) break; pos = x.quot;` instead of `/` and `%`, as it will return both the quotient and remainder with only one division operation instead of the two your current code uses...

Comment: @twalberg: That seems like a sensible improvement, but for some reason my benchmark is slightly worse with that alteration (104s compared with 90s). Might that be something to do with a specific library? Or perhaps just the overhead of having a struct variable in the function?

Comment: Might depend on your compiler and optimization flags as well. I would think `div()` should be inline-able, but if it's not, the function call overhead would probably kill any benefit you got from reducing the division instructions... If that's the case, it shouldn't be too hard to write your own inline assembly replacement for it, assuming your compiler has that capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you should return `max_ranks` is if `pos` equals zero.  Checking for this allows you to remove the conditional check from your for-loop.  This should improve both the worst case completion time, and speed of the looping for large values of max_ranks.

Here is my addition, plus a alternative way of avoiding the division operation.  I believe that this is as fast as a handwritten `div` like @twalberg was suggesting, unless there is some way to produce the remainder without a second multiplication.

I'm afraid since the most common answer is 0 (which doesn't even get past the first mod call) you aren't going to see much improvement.  My guess is that your average run time is very close to the run time of the modulus function itself.  You might try searching for a faster way to determine if a number is a factor of `pos`.  You don't actual need to calculate the remainder; you just need to know if there *is* a remainder or not.

Sorry if I made things confusing by restructuring your code.  I believe this will be slightly faster unless your compiler was already making these optimizations.

```
inline int corner_rank( int max_ranks, int *shape, int pos ) {
  // Most calls will not get farther than this.
  if (pos % shape[0] != 0) return 0;

  // One check here, guarantees that while loop below always returns.
  if (pos == 0) return max_ranks;

  int divisor = shape[0] * shape[1];
  int i = 1;
  while (true) {
    if (pos % divisor != 0) return i;
    divisor *= shape[++i];
  }
}
```

Also try declaring `pos` and `divisor` as the smallest types possible.  If they will never be greater than 255 you can use an `unsigned char`.  I know that some processors can perform a divide with smaller numbers faster than larger numbers, but you have to set your variable types appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, this has gained me get a roughly 20% speed improvement to my original function (I assume through the shortcut on most common case, and swapping division for multiply). It has also exposed a bug elsewhere that I can chase down.